# chrome display only 1 SWF embed

Tags: google-chrome, flash, embed

in HTML page we usually display 4 SWF embed and it's working good from years by IE and Chrome , but today chrome display only 1 SWF on the page and IE display All swf without any problem
i don't change any old code, i used this :

```
  <object
    classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"
    codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,260,0"
    id="55"
    width="366" height="150"
  >
    <param name="movie" value="flash/55.swf">
    <param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF">
    <param name="quality" value="high">
    <param name="seamlesstabbing" value="false">
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="samedomain">
    <embed
      type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
      pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/shockwave/download/index.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash"
      name="55"
      width="366" height="150"
      src="flash/55.swf"
      bgcolor="#FFFFFF"
      quality="high"
      seamlesstabbing="false"
      allowscriptaccess="samedomain"
    >
      <noembed>
      </noembed>
    </embed>
  </object>
```

if repeat the code 4 times chrome should display 4 flash in the page but it's display only 1 flash , IE display all

could you please help me

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same thing happened by me, i noticed that it's `Chrome 27` (new version from 2-3 days ago) that's causing the problem.

I didn't have the time to find the root problem yet, but i noticed that once you change one of the `<object>` attributes (even using the `Inspector`), the movie suddenly shows.

Then, as a quick-fix, i use this (assuming you're using `jQuery`):

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
    $('object').attr('width', $('object').attr('width'));
    });
```

**Edit:**

Apparently, there's an open issue about it: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=243290

**Update:**

New version from last night (`27.0.1453.116 m`) fixed the problem. more details: http://googlechromereleases.blogspot.co.il/2013/06/stable-channel-update_18.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are many solutions, you can force display by changing almost anything. For instance:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  if (window.navigator.appVersion.match(/Chrome/)) {
    $(function(){ $('object').css('zoom',1); });
  }
</script>
```